# Make `cargo doc` fail if there are warnings

Tags: testing, rust, documentation, rust-cargo, exit-code

I'd like to test in CI that `cargo doc` succeeds without any warnings. Is there any way to get `cargo doc` to exit with a non-zero exit code if there are warnings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/8424#issuecomment-774662296) should be helpful. Basically you can pass additional flags to the compiler by setting `RUSTFLAGS` env variable. So to deny all warnings (for any build type) is as simple as setting `RUSTFLAGS="-D warnings"`.

EDIT. To deny warnings in the generated documentation those flags must be set by `RUSTDOCFLAGS` env variable instead.

Comment: Unfortunatley that doesn't work for `cargo doc`; `RUSTFLAGS="-D warnings" cargo doc` seems to still allow the `rustdoc::broken_intra_doc_links` warning to be emitted as a warning rather than an error.

Comment: @joshlf Yup, I had this same issue. For `cargo doc` one needs to set `RUSTDOCFLAGS` instead (see the edit to the answer).